# docker CircleCI integration fails to start daemon

Tags: docker, daemon, circleci

I am executing a CircleCI script that should setup and install docker so that I can deploy to Dockerhub, however the Docker daemon will not start properly after installing it.

These are the circleCI automations that I want to setup

```
---
- run:
          name: Install Docker client
          command: |
            set -x
            VER="17.03.0-ce"
            curl -L -o /tmp/docker-$VER.tgz https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-$VER.tgz
            sudo tar -xz -C /tmp -f /tmp/docker-$VER.tgz
            sudo mv /tmp/docker/docker* /usr/bin/
            sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
            sudo chmod +x  /usr/bin/docker-compose  
            docker --version
            # sudo service docker stop
            sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
            sudo docker info            
            docker run hello-world

      - run:
         name: Build Docker image
         command: docker build -t joethecoder2/spring-boot-web:$CIRCLE_SHA1 .

      - run:
          name: Push to DockerHub
          command: |
            docker login -u$DOCKERHUB_LOGIN -p$DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
            docker push joethecoder2/spring-boot-web:$CIRCLE_SHA1
 ---
```

These are the error results, that show that the docker daemon will not start, even after trying to install, and start the daemon.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
set -x
VER="17.03.0-ce"
curl -L -o /tmp/docker-$VER.tgz https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-$VER.tgz
sudo tar -xz -C /tmp -f /tmp/docker-$VER.tgz
sudo mv /tmp/docker/docker* /usr/bin/
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x  /usr/bin/docker-compose  
docker --version
# sudo service docker stop
sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
sudo docker info            
docker run hello-world
+ VER=17.03.0-ce
+ curl -L -o /tmp/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100 26.5M  100 26.5M    0     0  57.4M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 57.3M
+ sudo tar -xz -C /tmp -f /tmp/docker-17.03.0-ce.tgz
+ sudo mv /tmp/docker/docker /tmp/docker/docker-containerd /tmp/docker/docker-containerd-ctr /tmp/docker/docker-containerd-shim /tmp/docker/docker-init /tmp/docker/docker-proxy /tmp/docker/docker-runc /tmp/docker/dockerd /usr/bin/
++ uname -s
++ uname -m
+ sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.9.0/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   617    0   617    0     0   6548      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6563

100 7857k  100 7857k    0     0  27.6M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 27.6M
+ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
+ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
+ sudo docker info
+ sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Exited with code 1
---
```

Why won't the Docker daemon connect properly inside CircleCI? I tried to start the daemon by doing:

```
sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
```

Why isn't the docker daemon running?

What are the script steps to get the docker service running in the script for circleCI?

Comment: Please use proper code formatting in your question and copy & paste as much of your CircleCI config as possible. The formatting right now makes it difficult to see what your config file is. Alternatively, link to a GitHub Gists or Pastbin.

Comment: The line `sudo docker info` appears above the daemon start. That's a bit surprising when looking at your script.